# React/Jest, test functions inside of functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component like so:

```js
export const FCContainer = function () {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
   const update = (details: {password: string}) => {
       dispatch({...details, user: user})
   };
   return <FCPresentational user={user} update={update}>
}
```

My coverage report says that the function update is not covered.

How do I test it?

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing your function, you would generally export it.  This would be used for complex functions that have critical functionality.

In this particular example you could refactor so you're passing an anonymous function along to the child component, or you can write an integration test that would render this component and children and test that the child correctly calls the `update` function.